# Run it in advance, sleep, and run at 12 am

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

When a code statement is made as follows, it must be executed 60 seconds before it can be executed at 12 am.

```
current_time = time.time()
time_to_sleep = (60 - (current_time % 60))
time.sleep(time_to_sleep)`
```

So I made a code statement as follows, and if I run it a few minutes ago, it will run at 12 am. But if you run it a few hours ago, the Chrome driver and Chrome browser will lose connection

```
current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
target_time = current_time.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0)
if current_time > target_time:
    target_time += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
time_difference = (target_time - current_time).total_seconds() / 3600
if time_difference >= 0:
    time.sleep(time_difference * 3600)
else:
    print("Target time is already in the past. No sleep needed.")`
```

I want to fix it to a code statement that won't disconnect even if I run it a few hours ago. Or I'd like to make a new code statement that I can wait until 12 am.

Comment: _But if you run it a few hours ago, the Chrome driver and Chrome browser will lose connection_ I don't see any Chrome driver code here...

Comment: Perhaps you could put the sleep code at the beginning of the program, before the Chrome driver is opened.